# Bourne Shell Script test throws error with two of same file-type in folder?

Tags: string, shell, syntax, sh

I am writing a Bourne Script and am looking to select files that match certain regular expressions.  I am doing this with an if test structure, and it identifies a file ending in ".o".  However, when there are two files in a directory which I am searching that end in ".o" I get the following error: "expr: syntax error".  How could this be possible?

```
    if test "`expr \"$file\" : ${SPECIFIED_DIRECTORY}/*.o`" != "0"; then
       do something
    fi
```

Comment: Think about it. The `*.o` regex is expanded before `expr` is run, so it's getting passed more than one argument on the right-hand side.

Comment: By the way, on modern systems `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh (which is actually closer to ksh88), not Bourne (which is quite literally a shell from the 70s). Are you sure you're **really** targeting Bourne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression test is almost certainly the wrong tool for the job here, but let's assume that `specified_directory` (lower-case by convention to avoid conflicts with environment variables and builtins) contained a regex to match a directory name, as opposed to a literal name, and thus actually **was** the right tool. If that were the case, you'd want to write...

```
if expr "$file" : "$specified_directory"/'.*[.]o' >/dev/null; then
  ...
fi
```

No test command, no subshell. Keep it simple.

If you don't escape the `.` (in this case, by making it a character class, `[.]`), it has its normal regular-expression meaning, of matching exactly one character. Similarly, `.*` is the way to match zero-or-more of any character in a regex, not bare `*` (which is the fnmatch syntax).

Comment: Thanks Charles!  My lack of experience makes me prone to bad decisions and misunderstanding.  I appreciate your pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if there are any `.o` files in the directory, then do something:

```
if find "$dir"/*.o >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # do something
fi
```

The `find` command will exit with success only if there are any matching files. Otherwise it will exit with failure, and the `then` block won't be executed. The `>/dev/null 2>&1` is to hide `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: `&>` is non-POSIX. The question explicitly calls for `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I replaced `ls` with `find`. Now it makes more sense. I don't know what drove me to use `ls` in the first place...

Comment: Well -- the way you're writing it there, the shell is expanding the glob before find is even started, and just passing find a list of already-expanded names (if they exist), or a nonexistant glob (if none do). That works, but I'm not sure using find is worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works on any POSIX shell, and calls no tools not available built-in to the shell, thus making it efficient at runtime.

```
contains_any_files() {
  set -- "$1"/*
  [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ -f "$1" ]
}

if contains_any_files "$dir"; then
   ...
fi
```